# How to use TPU on Kaggle/Colab with ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

I have a directory and dataframe that looks like this:

```
|---classA
|-----1.jpg
|-----2.jpg
|---classB
|-----23.jpg
|-----124.jpg
```

The dataframe consists of two columns: the image's name and its classes

```
name  | class
1.jpg |   1
2.jpg |   1
23.jpg|   2
```

I use [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) and use the method `flow_from_directory`. I am currently using GPU to train but since it is big it takes a lot of time, so I want to switch to TPU. I searched both Kaggle and Colab's TPU guide, and they use TFRecord to read the data. Can anyone help me how to use TFRecord from ImageDataGenerator?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use ImageGens on TPU!

Comment: Yeah, I just found the comment by Kaggle staff about IDG on TPU. Is there anyway that I can "replicate" IDG somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I find out that the ImageDataGenerator cannot be used on TPU. You have to use tf.data.Dataset instead.